# How to get stock movements data for a period of time in Square POS via API?

Tags: square-connect

I'm considering to create analytical application to use with Square POS. For the app to work I need to fetch products sale statistics, as well as current stocks and stock movements for a period of time. What objects should I use for these purposes? Do I have to use itemizations in the **Payment** object for sale statistcs and **Items** + **Inventory** objects for current stock? What about stock movements (inventory replenishments, write-offs etc.)?

Comment: hi..welcome to SO. Please read [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on SO. Add what you have done so far, expected out put in your question.

Comment: Hi! Yeah, I've read that, thanks. I'm pretty sure about Items & Inventory, just wanted confirmation from Square community. But I see no way to get stock movements for now. Asking here as per [Square FAQ](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/faq/) SO is the only way to reach Square tech support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your general approach sounds reasonable. Square doesn't track reasons for inventory (stock) changes (e.g. write-offs), only the amount is tracked. You can get the current stock amounts from the inventory endpoint for the merchant's entire catalog.You can track these changes either by polling the inventory endpoint at a fixed interval, or by [subscribing to webhook notifications](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/api/connect/v1/#enabling-webhooks) for the `INVENTORY_UPDATED` webhook, which will tell you when to check the inventory list for updates.